# Issue with Binding passed to TextField, it is not allowing state change

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

Hi all thanks in advance.

I am having an issue when running app (not in preview), a textfield is not updating the state. I've not continued to expand the MVVM yet as I am getting caught up in this UI/Binding issue.

Not sure what have I missed here? I am passing a StateObject (view model instance) into the EnvironmentObject list, which is then accessed from an EnvironmentObject and the models array of elements in a view is iterated over, then further passing the iterated elements of the array to a Binding in another view which is then bound to a textfield to be edited by the user?

Specifically, the issue is:
When swipe action > edit on an expense in the ContentView to navigate to EditExpenseView, the textfields don't allow editing.

Note:

- If I move the textfield up to the ExpenseList View, the binding to edit works. I thought that maybe the List(items) was the issue because it's iterating over an immutable collection.
- I am using the index and passing the array binding via $expenses[index] which is avoiding accessing the immutable collection as its only being used to get the index of the list item the user will edit.

If your still reading, **thanks for being awesome!**
Let me know if I can add any further information or provide clarity.

Expense Model:

```
struct Expense: Equatable, Identifiable, Codable {
    
    init(date: Date, description: String, amount: Decimal, type: ExpenseType, status: ExpenseStatus, budgetId: UUID?) {
        self.date = date
        self.description = description
        self.amount = amount
        self.type = type
        self.status = status
        self.budgetId = budgetId
    }
    
    static func == (lhs: Expense, rhs: Expense) -> Bool {
        lhs.id == rhs.id
    }
    
    var id: UUID = UUID()
    var date: Date
    var description: String
    var amount: Decimal
    var type: ExpenseType
    var status: ExpenseStatus
    var budgetId: UUID?
}
```

ExpenseViewModel:

```
class ExpenseViewModel: ObservableObject, Identifiable {
    
    @Published var expenses: [Expense] = []
    
    func insertExpense(date: Date, description: String, amount: Decimal, type: ExpenseType, status: ExpenseStatus) -> Void {
        expenses.insert(Expense(date: date, description: description, amount: amount, type: type, status: status, budgetId: nil), at:0)
    }
    
    func remove(_ expense: Expense) {
        expenses.removeAll(where: {$0.id == expense.id})
    }
    
}
```

App Entry:

```
import SwiftUI

@main
struct iBudgeteerApp: App {
    
    @StateObject private var expenses = ExpenseViewModel()
    
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView().environmentObject(expenses)
        }
    }
}
```

Initial View:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @EnvironmentObject private var model: ExpenseViewModel
    
    private static let formatter: NumberFormatter = {
        let formatter = NumberFormatter()
        formatter.numberStyle = .currency
        return formatter
    }()
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            VStack {
                Button("Add Row") {
                    model.insertExpense(date: Date(), description: "Groceries", amount: 29.94, type: .Expense, status: .Cleared)
                }
                ExpenseList(expenses: $model.expenses)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Expense List View:

```
struct ExpenseList: View {
    
    @Binding var expenses: [Expense]
    
    var formatter: NumberFormatter = {
        let formatter = NumberFormatter()
        formatter.numberStyle = .currency
        return formatter
    }()
    
    var body: some View {
        
        
        List (expenses.sorted(by: {$0.date > $1.date}).indices, id: \.self) {
            index in
            
            HStack {
                
                Text("\(index + 1).").padding(.trailing)
                
                VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                    
                    HStack {
                        Text(expenses[index].date.formatted(date:.numeric, time: .omitted))
                        Spacer()
                        Text(expenses[index].description)
                    }
                    
                    HStack {
                        Text(expenses[index].description)
                        Spacer()
                        Text("\(expenses[index].amount as NSNumber, formatter: formatter)")
                            .foregroundColor( expenses[index].type == .Expense ? .red : .green)
                        Image(systemName: expenses[index].type == .Expense ? "arrow.down" : "arrow.up").foregroundColor( expenses[index].type == .Expense ? .red : .green)
                    }.padding(.top, 1)
                }
                .swipeActions(edge: .trailing) {
                    Button(role: .destructive, action: { expenses.remove(at: index) } ) {
                        Label("Delete", systemImage: "trash")
                    }
                    .tint(.gray)
                }
                .swipeActions() {
                    NavigationLink {
                        EditExpenseView(expense: self.$expenses[index])
                    } label: {
                        Label("Edit", systemImage: "slider.horizontal.3")
                    }
                    .tint(.yellow)
            }
            }
        }
    }
    
}
```

Edit Expense View:

```
struct EditExpenseView: View {
    
    @Binding var expense: Expense
    
    var formatter: NumberFormatter = {
        let formatter = NumberFormatter()
        formatter.numberStyle = .currency
        return formatter
    }()
    

    var body: some View {
        
        Form {
            
            Section(header: Text("Editing: \(expense.description)")) {
                VStack {
                    DatePicker(
                        "Date",
                        selection: $expense.date,
                        displayedComponents: [.date]
                    )
                    HStack {
                        Text("Name")
                        Spacer()
                        TextField("description",text: $expense.description)
                            .fixedSize().multilineTextAlignment(.trailing)
                    }
                    HStack {
                        Text("Amount")
                        Spacer()
                        TextField("0.00", value: $expense.amount, formatter: formatter).fixedSize()
                    }
                    
                    Picker("Status", selection: $expense.status) {
                        ForEach(ExpenseStatus.allCases, id: \.self) {
                            status in
                            Text("\(status.rawValue)")
                        }
                    }
                    Picker("Type", selection: $expense.type) {
                        ForEach(ExpenseType.allCases, id: \.self) {
                            type in
                            Text("\(type.rawValue)")
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        
    }
}
```

---

**UPDATE**

It works in:

```
List ($expenses) { $expense in
    NavigationLink(expense.description) {
        EditExpenseView(expense: $expense)
    }         
}

ForEach($expenses) { $expense in
    NavigationLink(expense.description) {
        EditExpenseView(expense: $expense)
    }
}
```

But not in:

```
List($expenses) {
                $expense in
                
                    VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                        
                        HStack {
                            Text(expense.date.formatted(date:.numeric, time: .omitted))
                            Spacer()                        }
                        
                        HStack {
                            Text(expense.description)
                            Spacer()
                            Text("\(expense.amount as NSNumber, formatter: formatter)")
                                .foregroundColor( expense.type == .Expense ? .red : .green)
                            Image(systemName: expense.type == .Expense ? "arrow.down" : "arrow.up").foregroundColor(expense.type == .Expense ? .red : .green)
                        }.padding(.top, 1)
                    }
                    .swipeActions(edge: .trailing) {
                        Button(role: .destructive, action: { //expenses.remove(expense)
                        } ) {
                            Label("Delete", systemImage: "trash")
                        }
                        .tint(.gray)
                    }
                    .swipeActions() {
                        
                        NavigationLink {
                            EditExpenseView(expense: $expense)
                        } label: {
                            Label("Edit", systemImage: "slider.horizontal.3")
                        }
                        .tint(.yellow)
                    }
               
               
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer:

I couldn´t test this answer properly as your example is missing information and is not reproducible. Please consider posting a minimal reproducible example.

The issue is in these lines:

```
List (expenses.sorted(by: {$0.date > $1.date}).indices, id: \.self) {
```

and then doing:

```
EditExpenseView(expense: self.$expenses[index])
```

You are not passing a binding reference of `Expense` on to your `EditExpenseView` but a binding to a copy of it. You are breaking the binding chain.

The following aproach should yield the desired result:

```
List ($expenses) { $expense in
    HStack {
        
        Text("\(expenses.firstIndex(of: expense) + 1).").padding(.trailing)
        
        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
            
            HStack {
                Text(expense.date.formatted(date:.numeric, time: .omitted))
                Spacer()
                Text(expense.description)
            }
.....
```

and passing your `Expense` on to your subview:

```
EditExpenseView(expense: $expense)
```

Comment: Ok so I have narrowed the problem down.

Comment: Ok so I have narrowed the problem down thanks to you :) ty. 

Please see the updated code snippet at the bottom of the original post.  For some reason it works with both the short ForEach and List snippets, but the larger List code block is not working and I dont understand why, do you see anything wrong with it ?

Comment: @Dexmox it may be related to the swipe action. The only workaround I could think of, the top of my head, would be to pull the viewmodel inside `EditExpenseView` and  manipulate the expense directly in the viewmodel.

Comment: It definately is the swipe action causing this, do you know why it's dropping the binding? 

I have found a workaround, and your suggestion also worked, but I am now more curious to understand why it doesn't work than having it work haha.

Also thank you for your time and help :)

Comment: @Dexmox this is certainly an interesting topic. Two possibilities here. Edit your question and add what you did to create a workaround. Or create a new question. But i am not sure what would be the best way as the problem you described in your question is a combination of issues. Anyway, I would love to see your solution.